# QTWidgets QTableWidget crash with segfault

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

I have this signal on QPushButton:

```
void MainWindow::on_addNode_clicked()
{
    ui->nodesTable->insertRow(ui->nodesTable->rowCount());
    if(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()>1)
    {
        ui->nodesTable->item(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()-1, 0)->setText(ui->nodesTable->item(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()-2,0)->text());
    }
    else
    {
        ui->nodesTable->item(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()-1, 0)->setText(QString::fromStdString("0"));
    }
}
```

But it crashes with segmentation fault each time when I click the button. As I understood, item(...) give nullptr but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the first time there is no item in your table, your application crashed if pointer pointed non and when you want to reach it!

try this;

```
void MainWindow::on_addNode_clicked()
{
    ui->nodesTable->insertRow(ui->nodesTable->rowCount());
    if( !ui->nodesTable->rowCount() )
    {
        ui->nodesTable->item(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()-1, 0)->setText(ui->nodesTable->item(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()-2,0)->text());
    }
    else
    {
        ui->nodesTable->setItem(0, 0,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("New Item")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn’t specify the number of rows and columns your `QTableWidget` starts with 0 rows and 0 columns, adding 1 row still leaves you with 0 columns.

Additionally you have to create your items first via [`setItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setItem) before you can access them via [`item`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#item)

Please take a look at the [overview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#details) in the docs.

On another note:
In the `else` branch of your `if (ui->nodesTable->rowCount() > 1)` 
`rowCount() == 0` and therefore you access `ui->nodesTable->item(-1, 0)` which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the column count and you must set the item manually:

```
ui->nodesTable->setColumnCount(1);
ui->nodesTable->insertRow(ui->nodesTable->rowCount());
ui->nodesTable->setItem(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()-1, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("0") );
if(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()>1)
{
    ui->nodesTable->item(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()-1, 0)->setText(ui->nodesTable->item(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()-2,0)->text());
}
else
{
    ui->nodesTable->item(ui->nodesTable->rowCount()-1, 0)->setText(QString::fromStdString("0"));
}
```

Comment: But I made columns in UI disigner in QTCreator. And I need to set value from another row if it is there.